# Garmin USB insufficient permissions

Tags: permissions

Attempting to download GPX files from Garmin to QGIS. Error message states `insufficient permission or gpsbabel is missing`.

GPSbabel is part of the QGIS software, so I assume I need to change permissions.

```
sheep@pen:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 May 16 12:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
sheep@pen:~$ lsmod | grep garmin_gps
garmin_gps             32768  0
usbserial              57344  1 garmin_gps

sheep@pen:~$ groups
sheep adm lp dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

```
sudo journalctl --follow as far as I can see doesn't give device name.
```

> May 24 16:39:42 pen kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=091e, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 0.01
> May 24 16:39:42 pen kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
> May 24 16:39:42 pen mtp-probe[76479]: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
> May 24 16:39:43 pen mtp-probe[76479]: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
> May 24 16:39:43 pen mtp-probe[76482]: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4"
> May 24 16:39:44 pen mtp-probe[76482]: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device

The alternative commands, `ls -1 /dev >dev.before` and `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`
output identical files of 240 lines, no name there either

Thanks for your suggestions Waltinator

Comment: Is `gpsbabel` in your `PATH`? Do: `type --p gpsbabel`. Also try `gpsbabel -h`.

Comment: gpsbabel is in the PATH , but these suggestions haven't helped cheers

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I feel Linux no longer has any love from Garmin. I've opted for a gps with bluetooth, fingers crossed I have a work around.

Comment: Waltinator thanks for your suggestions. So far this issue isn't resolved

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I've used before. I hope it helps.

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/dvdrw"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.